# Debian 10 unmet dependencies

Tags: debian

I try to install dropbox from debian 10 software application but is shows the packages have unmet dependencies, how to fix it?

I already tried `sudo apt-get -f` install, update and upgrade.

[image]

Comment: Does Software have other logs you can check, to see if the "The following packages have unmet dependencies:" message was truncated in the toast notification and actually tells you what packages had problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article
[Installing Dropbox on Debian 10](https://linuxhint.com/install_dropbox_debian_10/)
has this procedure in detail:

- Download from the
  [download page of Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux)
  the Ubuntu 64/32-bit version that matches your configuration
- Navigate to the `~/Downloads` directory : `cd ~/Downloads`
- Update the APT package repository cache: `sudo apt update`
- Install Dropbox: `sudo apt install ./dropbox*.deb`
- Install the python3-gpg package using APT: `sudo apt install python3-gpg`
- Reboot: `sudo reboot`
- Run Dropbox from the Application Menu. This will launch the installation,
  so click on OK to continue.
- Once the download is complete, the browser should open to login to your
  Dropbox account

If all went well,
a `~/Dropbox` directory should be created in your HOME directory
for your files and directories, and Dropbox will automatically sync all changes.
In the File Manager, you should be able to upload files and directoris by
right-click option "Dropbox > Move to Dropbox".